# How to split a string by hours:minutes:seconds using Java

Tags: java

I've got strings that have the following format:

```
Text 11:54:02 Text
[1]"Fri Sep 19 11:07:24 +"RT @OliverBullough: Andrei Yakunin, investor son of Putin's friend Vladimir, on Russian deals: \"2014 is lost, 2015 is effectively lost.\" ht\u2026"
```

Where Text is just normal text and the `11:54:02` is the time. Now the time varies constantly, so we could have 11:53:11 or 02:01:01 etc. I would like to know if it is possible to split by this time i.e

```
[Text][Time][Text]
[[1]"Fri Sep 19] [11:07:24][ +"RT @OliverBullough: Andrei Yakunin, investor son of Putin's friend Vladimir, on Russian deals: \"2014 is lost, 2015 is effectively lost.\" ht\u2026"]
```

So that I can just read the first and second text values. I've tried using the following split but it doesn't seem to work:

```
String[] Timesplit = fileContent.split("0-9:0-9:0-9");
```

Ideally I would want `Timesplit[0]` to have `[1]"Fri Sep 19` and `Timesplit[2]` to have  `+"RT @OliverBullough: Andrei Yakunin, investor son of Putin's friend Vladimir, on Russian deals: \"2014 is lost, 2015 is effectively lost.\" ht\u2026"`

Is it possible to split the data?

Comment: Can you provide us with code where you show us what you have done?

Comment: what is ur expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used this regex

```
([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})
```

.

```
String fileContent="[1]\"Fri Sep 19 11:07:24 +\"RT @OliverBullough: Andrei Yakunin, investor son of Putin's friend Vladimir, on Russian deals: \\\"2014 is lost, 2015 is effectively lost.\\\" ht\\u2026\"";
String[] Timesplit = fileContent.split("([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})");
System.out.println(Timesplit[0]);
System.out.println(Timesplit[1]);
```

output>>

```
[1]"Fri Sep 19 
 +"RT @OliverBullough: Andrei Yakunin, investor son of Putin's friend Vladimir, on Russian deals: \"2014 is lost, 2015 is effectively lost.\" ht\u2026"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just split the string by ":"

```
String[] split = fileContent.split(":");
```

So "11:54:02" will return ["11", "54", "02"]

"0-9:0-9:0-9" doesn't seem to be a regex, which means `fileContentSplit("0-9:0-9:0-9")` will actually try to find "0-9:0-9:0-9" within the string and split it by that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write [0-9] instead of 0-9.

Answer (score 1):

Use this,
String[] split = fileContent.split("[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]");

Thanks.